# Convert Ordered and Unordered List to readable text with bullets/numbers on pasting in HTML textarea element

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, addeventlistener, onchange

I'm trying to find a solution to convert ordered and unordered list from a webpage when copy-pasted to a textarea should be converted to readable list.

Please check following fiddle for better explanation:

https://jsfiddle.net/bodmwghj/2/

```
<textarea id="final"></textarea>
```

If we copy paste list from webpage to our input textarea field it loses the "bullets" / "numbers"

Instead if we can prepend the list items with atleast a bullet • symbol and a space that would make more sense and would keep text still readable without having to allow HTML or using tinyMCE editors.

I feel this would be more tricky but if we can append incremental numbers to ordered list, nothing like it, but I am okay to bring bullets there as well if numbers can't be generated on the fly.

So far I could find addEventListener for "paste" event, but I am confused how I can reach the desired solution.

Please let me know if I can explain any further. Hope I can find a solution to this. Any help / possible pointers to solutions is appreciated.

EDIT: Copied text may include formatted HTML and other text. Requirement is only to convert lists. JS Fiddle URL updated.

Comment: It is a [**text**area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) not an _HTML_ area. Plain text only. So you'll have to use numbers and UTF-8 character codes for • - as you said, you'll have to parse each line separately and prepend the style you would like. I have no idea how you will determine which style (number vs. bullet) though.

Comment: Here's a fiddle that will give you and idea of how to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/vgsc6pwb/

Comment: @RandyCasburn this works if copied text only has list, but copied text may have other text as well. It can also include HTML formatted text.

Comment: Then please reread my first comment. The solution, given the yet unmentioned constraints (as they continue to increase as time goes by), the logical solution is to use a block level element (such as a `<div>` and make it `contentEditable`. Then, since it is an HTMLElement, you can paste all of your HTML in there and it will work. But there are CSS considerations and the form will not contain the content. So, upon submission, you' have to paste the `textContent` from the `contentEditable` `<div>` back into a hidden `<textarea>` to be submitted with the form.Alternatively you could use formdata.

Comment: See my updated fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/vgsc6pwb/1/